# The absolute limits of photosynthesis

Tags: creature-design, hard-science, flora, genetic-engineering, agriculture

I have found that some crops, like sugarcane, have a photosynthetic efficiency of 12%. Using extensive genetic modification and eliminating all natural barriers, like light wavelength, chloroplast density, photorespiration, glucose conversion or even plant color, what's the theoretical limit of photosynthesis?

Assuming artificial 24 hour lighting, what changes can be done to increase photosynthetic efficiency and what would be the limits of said changes.

Comment: you are asking two different questions here, while we want only one per post.

Comment: This question is a huge one.   Just one of the variables you list could be a pHd dissertation.   An example: this [12 page review on manipulating RUBSICO](https://academic.oup.com/jxb/article/54/386/1321/568648) .  Maybe it would help if you would lay out the scenario you are using this question for.   A fiction?  High school science project to build our world better?  Then there could be a more directed and purpose-built answer useful for your endeavor.

Comment: 12% - nope. Most photosynthesis is between 3-5% efficient, the maximum theoretically possible is 11%. You might want to dig into some research, then figure out what worldbuilding problem you want help solving here. (Only 45% of sunlight incident on the surface of Earth is within wavelengths which are useful to plants - so the figure of efficiency to total light is even less). Have you thought of getting an upgrade for your star?

Comment: I can't say I'm fond of the idea, but see https://phys.org/news/2022-06-artificial-photosynthesis-food-sunshine.html

Comment: There is a lot of research on using LEDs for indoor farming, not just on optimizing the wavelength but also the timing of when to illuminate the plants.

Comment: @Topcode - the article I cited describes using solar panels.  I'm skeptical of the concept and *more* skeptical of eating acetate-fed algae/yeast/mushrooms in the place of food, but I didn't look deep into this paper and just posted it as a source to ponder.

Comment: [tag:hard-science] for uninvented tech? What are your expectations? Anyone who could answer this question with a substantial improvement would be running to the patent office. (See [Advice concerning questions asking HOW to implement a technological procedure or device](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609).)

Comment: related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/is-photosynthesis-60-efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 2008 [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.copbio.2008.02.004) that tries to answer this question. They compare C3 and C4 photosynthesis.

[image]

Switching to LEDs you can try to match the spectrum and claim that improves efficiency, but LEDs are typically around 40-50 % wall plug efficiency so it kind of matters how you want to define the efficiency.

There are a lot of urban and indoor farming concepts, as well as greenhouse concepts where people are actively working on your question. A lot of time the value proposition is actually in the saving of water and maybe transportation costs. But I think a substantial part of the work is understanding the timing of when to illuminate the plants and understanding the phenotyping of the plants. By phenotyping, is the plant thin and spindly and wasting energy, how broad the leaves are etc and how that connects to the plant genetics. Apparently having some UV or Blue portion of the spectrum is important for some of this. There will probably be issues with plant disease, and while it is not important for plants like lettuce, some plants are stronger and more robust if they are exposed to wind forces.

With indoor lighting with LEDs that don't produce as much heat, you can have higher light intensities which helps the productivity.

> Elevated light intensities made possible with LEDs increased photosynthetic activity, the number of tillers, biomass and yield. At lower light intensities, blue, green and far-red light operated antagonistically during the stem elongation period. High photosynthetic activity was achieved when at least 50% of red light was applied during cultivation. A high proportion of blue light prolonged the juvenile phase, while the shortest flowering time was achieved when the blue to red ratio was around one. Blue and far-red light affected the glutathione- and proline-dependent redox environment in leaves. LEDs, especially in Blue, Pink and Red Low Light (RedLL) regimens improved flour quality by modifying starch and protein content, dough strength and extensibility as demonstrated by the ratios of high to low molecular weight glutenins, ratios of glutenins to gliadins and gluten spread values. These results clearly show that LEDs are efficient for experimental wheat cultivation, and make it possible to optimize the growth conditions and to manipulate metabolism, yield and quality through modification of light quality and quantity. This other [paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2018.00605/full#T1) seems to be enthusiastic about LEDs and Wheat, but seems to compare to fluorescent lights rather than the sun. But in general it is complicated and will be interesting to see what happens over the next 20 years or so.